# Weird behavior in Reducer of a MapReduce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Following is the code for a Reducer function I'm using in a MapReduce job.
It should return the value from the iterator + custom string ("***---") appended to to each value.
But instead it is appending custom string twice.

For example if the value is abc then
instead of printing

```
abc***---
```

It is printing

```
abc***---***---
```

Why is that happening?

The code:

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

        while (values.hasNext()) {

            Text t=values.next();
            String s = "***---";

            t.append(s.getBytes(), 0, s.length());

            output.collect(key, t); 

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using your Reducer class also as a `Combiner`?  If so, the operation in the Reducer will be applied twice: once during the Combine phase (after Map, before shuffle/sort), and again during the Reduce phase.

Comment: Your answer is most likely right, but some additional details: Hadoop doesn't actually guarantee that the combiner is ran, or that it's ran exactly once, generally it might be executed 0-N times.

Comment: Yes. That's precisely is what happened. I had used the same class for combiner also. Removed that and now code is working fine. Thanks anyway! :)